# How to slow down block production?

Tags: besu

I have a Besu private network. The genesis file was created by me.
I wonder how I could slow down block production speed.

I already changed `blockperiodseconds` to 6 or 10 but I started to see some "Invalid block" because the production time is below the value I put in genesis. Ex: if I configure blockperiodseconds to 10 seconds and the node produces a block faster than this an
an error is thrown.

Is safe to ignore this error?

To be honest I can't remember now if it is an error or a warning. Seems threatening to me anyway.

```
{
  "config" : {
    "chainId" : 8658,
    "berlinBlock" : 0,
    "ibft2" : {
      "blockperiodseconds" : 2,
      "blockreward": "50000000",
      "epochlength" : 30000,
      "requesttimeoutseconds" : 4
    }
  },
  "nonce" : "0x0",
  "timestamp" : "0x58ee40ba",
  "gasLimit" : "0x1fffffffffffff",
  "contractSizeLimit" : 2147483647,
  "difficulty" : "0x1",
  "mixHash" : "0x63746963616c2062797a616e74696e65206661756c7420746f6c6572616e6365",
  "coinbase" : "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
  "alloc" : {
    "fe3b557e8fb62b89f4916b721be55ceb828dbd73" : {
      "balance" : "0xad78ebc5ac6200000"
    },
    "627306090abaB3A6e1400e9345bC60c78a8BEf57" : {
      "balance" : "99900000000000000000000"
    },
    "f17f52151EbEF6C7334FAD080c5704D77216b732" : {
      "balance" : "99900000000000000000000"
    }
  },
  "extraData" : "0xf87ea00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000f85494048beb263400d984f601b76f6eb939e343f7b92794c3febddd6735504041be98e47e5a0a9bea62be3a9474d24115f3543402542f769db352a9a6aeaf06b994e4c49276c0b76b9f96d721768c687d2117403ff1808400000000c0"
}
```

Comment: Can you include the genesis file to replicate your network?

Comment: @OZ_ done! It is a basic genesis from tutorial (same wallets too) with few changes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- It's not OK to ignore the `"Invalid block"` warning, it means that something is misconfigured.

---

Due to that *[on a network that is running **already**]* making *(what's called)* a ***TRANSITION*** from your old `blockperiodseconds` to a new *value* is **NOT** just as simple as just editing the value in your genesis file *(like you would normally do for a completely new Besu network's setup)*, you should utilize the **Transition** module (**as described here:** https://besu.hyperledger.org/private-networks/how-to/configure/consensus/ibft#transitions).

---

I suggest you to try something like that for your network:

```json
{
  "config" : {
    "chainId" : 8658,
    "berlinBlock" : 0,
    "ibft2" : {
      "blockperiodseconds" : 2,
      "blockreward": "50000000",
      "epochlength" : 30000,
      "requesttimeoutseconds" : 4
    },
    "transitions": {
      "ibft2": [
        {
          "block": <FutureBlockNumber>,
          "blockperiodseconds": <NewValue>
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "nonce" : "0x0",
  "timestamp" : "0x58ee40ba",
  "gasLimit" : "0x1fffffffffffff",
  "contractSizeLimit" : 2147483647,
  "difficulty" : "0x1",
  "mixHash" : "0x63746963616c2062797a616e74696e65206661756c7420746f6c6572616e6365",
  "coinbase" : "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
  "alloc" : {
    "fe3b557e8fb62b89f4916b721be55ceb828dbd73" : {
      "balance" : "0xad78ebc5ac6200000"
    },
    "627306090abaB3A6e1400e9345bC60c78a8BEf57" : {
      "balance" : "99900000000000000000000"
    },
    "f17f52151EbEF6C7334FAD080c5704D77216b732" : {
      "balance" : "99900000000000000000000"
    }
  },
  "extraData" : "0xf87ea00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000f85494048beb263400d984f601b76f6eb939e343f7b92794c3febddd6735504041be98e47e5a0a9bea62be3a9474d24115f3543402542f769db352a9a6aeaf06b994e4c49276c0b76b9f96d721768c687d2117403ff1808400000000c0"
}
```

- Where the `<FutureBlockNumber>` is the block number that has not been mined yet, and since which the changes to the `blockperiodseconds` will take effect;
- It's always recommended that `requesttimeoutseconds` should be `2x` greater than the `blockperiodseconds`

*Example values:*

```json
{
  "block": <FutureBlockNumber>,
  "blockperiodseconds": 10,
  "requesttimeoutseconds": 20
}
```

> The transitions genesis configuration item allows you to specify a
> future block number at which to change IBFT 2.0 network configuration
> in an existing network. For example, you can update the block time,
> block reward, or mining beneficiary.

**Make sure to restart all the nodes after with the updated genesis file.**

---

Hopefully, that helps you.

Comment: Sorry, but it seems like you didn't understand my question. My network is running indeed, but every time I change anything in genesis file I simply reset it all to begin again. So my question is not about how to CONFIGURE this value. It was working as expected anyway. My question is about WHY the nodes are complaining when a block is produced faster then that value. I'm afraid of that. Ex. If I configure a value of 10 like you suggest and a node produces a block in 3 it will complain (witha warning or error I can't remember )

Comment: I'll reward you anyway because you gave attention to this question. But please tell me why it is allowed to put a high value in ```blockperiodseconds``` if the node start to cry when a block is produced faster.

Comment: Wait a minute! time to reflection ... On second thought I'm not sure if I restarted the entire network... Are you telling me that if this value starts high, a block will never be produced faster than that?

Comment: Thank you for the reward :) *Re "Are you telling me that if this value starts high, a block will never be produced faster than that?"*, **yes**, I believe it should work like that. The error might be because not all nodes have been restarted with the new genesis file, and they have the old `blockperiodseconds` value in a closure. Here's a reference from the docs which might be related to that: ...

Comment: `When adding a new node, if a TimeStampMoreRecentThanParent | Invalid block header error occurs, the genesis file of the new node specifies a higher blockperiodseconds than the imported chain. The imported chain makes new blocks faster than the genesis file allows and Besu rejects them with this error. This error most often occurs when importing chains from older versions of Besu.`

Comment: Though it references a different error, but I believe that can apply to the error you've been getting, too. Please make sure that all the nodes have been restarted and transitioned to the new `blockperiodseconds` and `requesttimeoutseconds` values. Hopefully, the error should go away.

Comment: Very well. I'll check all these details again having this in mind. Many thanks.